# Accessing Registered Servers over Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, excel

With DBs in different countries, different servers but same structure, I have created registered server to access them when running certain queries for reports on SSMS. Thus far this is ok.
However, I would like to enhance this and have the end users be able to extract the data over Excel.(already able to do this but on individual countries).
How can I use MS Excel to extract data from registered servers.

All this is on SSMS 2008 r2.

Comment: It's not clear what users should see. All the data? Data specific to a country? How is Excel accessing the data? Is Excel unable to query a four-part name?

Comment: end data which is the result from a query, all the data from all the countries.
Question is how Excel can access the data.
Let me read up on FourPart name.

Answer (score 0):

If using excel to get the data , you can always depend on external data link function.

Create new excel 2013 and click data ribbon. 
Click "from other sources", click "sql server"
After that follow the wizard. 
It is better that you create a specific view to pump the data to excel as the wizard only recognize table and view.

If you want to distribute the excel make sure to save the password on the excel file. 
Also create a user role specific to excel export is advised.

Whenever user want to get a fresh data, just click refresh on data ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by "registered servers".

There are 2 options here:

1. registered servers in your local SSMS

   > They are stored in your local windows registry and can't be reached by Excel from another PCs.
2. central management server (CMS) and central repository of known SQL servers

   > In this case you can connect from Excel to the repository (CMS), get list of registered/known servers (2 tables in msdb database of your CMS server) and connect to them one-by-one getting data needed.

How to create CMS server :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group